# Callback for wp.autosave.server.triggerSave();

Tags: posts, pages, callbacks, autosave

I'm using following code to force WordPress page to save post as draft, is there any callback function for it, I want to alert a text after it complete saving post as draft.

```
if ( wp.autosave.server ) {
wp.autosave.server.triggerSave();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found the solution, callback function for when post or page is:

```
jQuery(document).on('heartbeat-tick.autosave', function( event, data ) {
    // your code here
});
```

This uses the [Wordpress Heartbeat API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/).

Comment: Yes. Here is WordPress Heartbeat API which allows to send any additional data to the server. I thought to write a detailed response but it seems you already solve your issue :)